# Unable to install sails.js

Tags: npm, sails.js

I have node installed on my computer ( which node returns a path) but when i run the commmand:

```
sudo npm -g install sails
```

It will run with some warnings but no errors. After installing i try to run

```
which sails
```

But it returns nothing and I cannot run any sails commands.

```
-bash: sails: command not found
```

I am using Mac with the stock Iterminal.
Warnings that i get:

```
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
```

Comment: What research have you done?  What warnings do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this into the terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

Also, sometimes you have to restart the terminal application or your computer before it will work correctly, so give that a try.

Comment: Tried to restart and tried to run ur suggestion before running it again. doesnt seem to help

Comment: I would guess that npm's bin folder is not in that location then. It sounds like you need to find npm's bin folder and add it to the path like above.